# New nav not displaying the correct number of posts

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, new-nav

I volunteered for the new-nav, and I don't see the expected number of posts.  I'm supposed to see 15, but I only see 11/15.

This is only when I use the "collapsed layout toggle" option on Meta.  This works on SO, and also if I use the "expanded layout toggle" option or sort by "recently active"

[image: Wrong number]

#### Suspected cause

I think this correlates to the fact that 4/15 of the posts have scores below the -8 threshold and would be grayed out.  The screenshot below shows 3 of the 4 missing posts when using the "Expanded layout" (the fourth was too far away to fit in my screenshot).

[image: Some of the "missing" posts]

If it's relevant, I'm running Chrome 43 on Windows 7.

Comment: is this still a thing? marking as no repro for now

Comment: Haven't checked since the most recent update to the new nav.  It's probably gone since I don't even see an analogy to those controls, but I'll ping you if it recurs.

Comment: @Sklivvz yep it seems to be gone now.  On another note, it's really hard to switch from expanded to collapsed on the home tab.  I have to visit a different one and change the setting there.  Then I can return to the home tab with the setting persisted over.